# mongodb and authenticate and passport in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, passport.js

i have a collection like this in mongodb

```
{
   username:silver,
   Email:sil@gmail.com,
   password:silvester,
}
```

so to authenticate i will fetch data from database and then i will check given email is exist or not with if statement like this

```
app.post("/login",function(req,res){

   var email=req.body['emailid'];

   collection.find({email:sil@gmail.com}).toArray(function(err,res)
   {
      if(res.length==0){
         console.log("name is not exist");
      }else{
         if(res.email==email){
            console.log("email is exist");
         }else{
            console.log("not exist");
         }
      }
   });
});
```

so here how to use passport module for authentication.let me know it with sample code with configuration.
i am using express3.x framework .so how to configure it also.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/) you can read about local strategies, and [here](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/) about configure.

Your local strategy should look like this:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        emailField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'passw',
    },

    function (emailField, passwordField, done) {
        process.nextTick(function () {
            db.collection(dbCollection, function (error, collection) {
                if (!error) {
                    collection.findOne({
                        'email': sil@gmail.com
                        'password': silvester // use there some crypto function
                    }, function (err, user) {
                        if (err) {
                            return done(err);
                        }
                        if (!user) {
                            console.log('this email does not exist');
                            return done(null, false);
                        }
                        return done(null, user);
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log(5, 'DB error');
                }
            });
        });
    }));
```

Comment: should i write above coding within post request like         app.post('/login',function(req,res){passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        emailField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'passw',
    }, })            let me know it..

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good idea. Also, do not forget to about `passport.serializeUser` and `passport.deserializeUser`.

Comment: how to use passport for authenticate the data of mongodb.

Comment: In your `app.post`, you can use `passport.authenticate`. All of this information is in the [documentation](http://passportjs.org/guide/)

Comment: my doubt is after give login data like emailid and password i will post that to server by using app.post() so i will keep that value in different variable in post method after how to pass that data by using passport.use() or passport.authenticate() and then how to check that data exist is database (i am not telling about query,i am asking that where i have to write that query and how to comapre that data) i am not a familiar for node.js so let me know it.thanks

Comment: if i use like this app.post('/logindata',passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                                       failureRedirect: '/login/error',

                                                    })

);
how can i get logindata to pass