# Pulling user's name and photo with Passport.js

Tags: node.js, github, github-api, passport.js

I am developing a node.js app and recently figured out how to authenticate via GitHub. I want to know if there is a way to pull a user's profile photo and name so I can display it elsewhere in the app. I [found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399635/passportjs-profile-undefined-name), but it looks like Facebook and Google use different methods of obtaining these things.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passport module developers usually normalize the user profile object so some standard fields are available in the same way across all modules in this way:

1. **profile.id** - assigned by the provider
2. **profile.username** - their 'login'
3. **profile.displayName** - full name of the user
4. **profile.profileUrl** - user's profile page on the provider's site
5. **profile.emails** - array of email addresses, but usually just a single address

Thus, you already have the username and/or displayname.  One down!

These cover what is consistently needed, but providers can return other information.  This naturally depends upon (a) what kind of services the provider offers and (b) the requested scopes.

The provider-specific info isn't lost. It is stored in `profile._json` next to the normalized properties...and inspecting this will show what else you have to work with.

For Github profile photos/images, you'll be looking for a `gravatar_id` property to get the user's photo URL.

You can confirm this, using the boilerplate example from `passport-github` for illustration purposes only, you could do something like this to see what Github is handing back to you so you can evaluate the entire provider response:

```
passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
    // authentication stuff here, per `passport-github` docs
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      // skipping error handling &c for brevity...
      fs.writeFile("githubProfile.json", JSON.stringify(profile));
      return done(null, profile);
    });
  }
));
```

If correct, you could then grab the user photo URL from `profile._json.gravatar` for use in whatever way you need (saving to database, inserting into a profile page, etc).

Comment: I added your `fs.writeFile` line to my code and saw the json file generated. Sweet! Do you know if variables declared in app.js is available across my app, universally? Like, can make a variable ID for username and call it in my other scripts.

Comment: This really starts into a whole new and very large topic. Short answer is "yes". If your program is short, you'll need to understand "variable scope" in javascript.   If you have your app broken into smaller files, read up on node's module docs and functions. If you haven't used javascript much, do both in that order. ...and in the meantime, if this answered your original question, is appreciated if you approved it as an answer. :)

Comment: Ah, whoops! I was looking at this on Friday and forgot about it after work. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone coming across this question in the future...

If you are using node.js, you will know that you won't be able to access files outside of your app folder. This is irritating if you are trying to access the compiled JSON file, so I got around this by making sure it was generated within the app (`system/account/githubProfile.json` in my case). I then used `$.getJSON` to grab that file. `console.log(data.username);` and `console.log(data._json.avatar_url);` will give you a username and gravatar respectively.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't have to save the data to a file to use it. That was just a way to show (a) what's received and (b) lets you open the file in your editor.  You could (and probably should) replace the `fs.writeFile` with user lookup/save/update database calls. There are also [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286824/mongodb-and-authenticate-and-passport-in-node-js) [helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639476/passport-js-authenticate-users-from-mongodb-with-passport-local?rq=1) questions here that can get you started, if needed.  Best luck!

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the update! Your advice is and has been super helpful.